# onActivityResult doesn't work?

Tags: android

I am facing with a problem related startActivityForResult()

To start SecondActivity from FirstActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key1", "12345");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And handles result :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //TODO handle here. 
}
```

To send the message to FirstActivity from SecondActivity :

in SecondActivity :

```
setResult(0);
```

I can't handle the result on onActivityResult in FirstActivity.
It never works for my application.

My OS is : 1.5

What is wrong here?

Comment: what happens when you finish the second Activity? Is the callback method onActivityResult() invoked?

Comment: Thanks for respose, I am trying to make it be keeping second activity and First activity would be finished. Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`startActivityForResult` is meant to be used for situations where you want to select a piece of data, or perform some sort of action that your `Activity` or application cannot do.

For example, you want to pick a contact, so you launch the contacts application, the user chooses the person they want, and you get sent the result.  Or you want to take a photo, so you launch the camera application and ask it to send you the photo once it's done.  This action is completely separate from your first activity that calls `startActivityForResult`.

The `Activity` you're launching will not send you the result until that `Activity` has completed, i.e. `finish()` has been called.

So in your case, you need to call this in `SecondActivity`:

```
setResult(...);
finish();
```

before `FirstActivity` will receive the result in its `onActivityResult` method.  Of course, this means that `SecondActivity` is now gone and `FirstActivity` is top of the stack again.

---

It's not possible to send the result to `FirstActivity` then close it while  keeping `SecondActivity` still active.  In this case you should just handle whatever this 'result' is in `SecondActivity`, or send it off to a `Service` you define to do whatever processing it is you want.

Comment: I had some issues with my codes ...the onActivityResult was not being invoked..at last figured out that I was using startActivity(newIntent); instead of setResult(resultCode,intent);...thanks for this post..

Answer (score 19):

I was stuck here for a while. Adding my problem here to make sure that you don't scratch your head as well.

The second parameter of this function has to be 0 or higher.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // <- this is OK
```

I was setting the second parameter to RESULT_OK, which is -1, and my onActivityResult callback was never getting called. So if you get stuck like me, you can also check if your second parameter is correct.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK); // <- this is wrong
```

The above line will fail to call onActivityResult.

Answer (score 7):

I was also stuck on the same problem - but due to a different reason as *matangs*. Apparently `startActivityForResult` only works if you have `android:launchMode` set to `standard` for main activity (in manifest). Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Removing launchmode from activity also fixed my problem...Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems ok, but do you stop your second activity ?

Try this in it :

```
setResult(0);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for respose, I am trying to make it be keeping second activity and First activity would be finished. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I am trying to make that :

when setResult(MY_RESULT) to FirstActivity, I can handle it on onActivityResult. Then finish FirstActivity. such as FirstActivity.this.finish(); 

How to do it ?

Comment: If you want FirstActivity finish after getting the result of the SecondActivity, you can of course execute a finish() on FirstActivity too.

Comment: setResult(0) results in a failed result. I think the result needs to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing actions on onPause (like unbinding a service) try to comment it and see if onActivityResult is called (I wasted few good hours on this..)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @johndodo (that point to the manifiest) - I find my solution for the same problem.

removing `android:noHistory=true` at the manifiest" solved this problem for me.