# onActivityResult never called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

So far, I used the startActivity function with success and now that I need to use the startActivityResult, I have a problem.

When using this function, the activity I expect to be launched is launched correctly but it seems like the onActivityResult function is never called.

Here is my code in the FriendPicker activity, to lauch the MoodPicker activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FriendPicker.this, MoodPicker.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

And here is my code in the MoodPicker activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{                   
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Result");                        

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 2:             
            Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Resut 2");                

            break;
    }
}
```

and nothing in my logfile is written (I of course, checked that my log file was working properly and double check with a text view output).

Is there something I forgot to declare in the Manifest file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you add the [`setResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) call in your MoodPicker class ?

Comment: Please add your solution so that other users reading this post can find useful help.

Answer (score 28):

I had same problem and  solved it:
Just remove

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: This issue was driving me crazy, well spotted

Comment: Just wasted a few hours on this. Lifesaver right here.

Comment: ohhh really very very thanks. i waste my 5 hour for this and finally got it with your solution.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I didn't realize I was calling `startActivityForResult` from an activity that had the `android:noHistory` attribute set to true in the manifest. Therefore, the `onActivityResult` was never called as there was no activity instance anymore.

Comment: I was stuck with this problem for hours. Then I saw your answer and realized I had made the same mistake. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: YES. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9):

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

like

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

will stop onActivityResult from receive result.

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask"
poses the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

If I am reading this right, all the code referenced needs to be in "FriendPicker".  In "MoodPicker" you need code like this that sets the result and ends itself:

```
this.setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, i);
this.finish();
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: You mean that all the code I wrote should be in the FriendPicker activity? Cause if it is so, there is something I don't get at all in the startActivityForResult process.

Comment: I tried putting the onActivityResult function in my FriendPicker class and lo log either. I don't get it...

Comment: onActivityResult() should be placed in the Activity where you called startActivityForResult()

Answer (score 6):

There is bug in android API. In startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
This funktion does work as long as requestCode = 0. However, if you change the request code to 
anything other than zero, the ApiDemos will fail (and OnActivityResult won't be called). 
Found here:

[EDIT: Link removed as google group overrun with spam]

Comment: Actually it will work with any requestCode >= 0. Anything negative however doesn't.

Comment: THANKS!! by mistake I was sending a -1 and the instruction works (I meen it opens the Activity) but then it does not receive data, so you have to add a code >= 0

Answer (score 3):

*FriendPicker activity*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FriendPicker.this, MoodPicker.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{                   
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Result");                        

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 2:             
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {     //optional   
            Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Resut 2");                
              }
            break;
    }
}
```

*MoodPicker class*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MoodPicker.this, FriendPicker.class);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

I had the same problem using onActivityResult(); cause i didn´t understand how this will be correctly applied, here you can find a good explanation how to use onActivityResult
[onActivityResult doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984233/onactivityresult-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that I had made was that after creating my Intent I was calling `startActivity()` instead of `startActivityForResult()`

Sometimes the simple ones kill you :)

Answer (score 0):

My silly mistake. Might help someone.

I kept **onActivityResult(...)** in another class. 
It has to be as a method in the class where the **startActivityForResult()** is called.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're wondering about this in react-native in a native module:

in your MainActivity:

```java
...
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

in your Module:

```java
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

    final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    Promise promise;

    public GeneralIntentModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        this.reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyModule ";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void captureVideo(Promise promise) {
        this.promise = promise;
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(this.reactContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            this.reactContext.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        this.promise.resolve(data.getDataString());
    }
}
```