# onActivityResult() method not being called in an activity that extends SherlockMapActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

I have an activity "SearchActivity" which extends SherlockActivity. In this activity I have an options menu which has a search bar and a "Go" button. The data that is entered in the search bar has to be passed to the previous activity "NavigationActivity" which extends SherlockMapActivity.

This is a part of my code of SearchActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.go:
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.putExtra("SearchText", enteredText);
           setResult(200, intent);
           startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
           finish();
           break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the onActivityResult() method in NavigationActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("In onActivityResult method");
    if(data != null && resultCode == 200 && requestCode == 100) {
        String text = data.getStringExtra("SearchText");
        System.out.println("The data is: " + text);
        Toast.makeText(this, "The text entered in the search bar is: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }       
}
```

The problem is that the onActivityResult() method is never getting called in the NavigationActivity. On pressing the "Go" button I'm able to navigate from the SearchActivity to the NavigationActivity but not able to get the get the data in the NavigationActivity. Could you please help me in this aspect?

Thank you.

Comment: http://forum.processing.org/topic/startactivityforresult-and-onactivityresult-not-returning-any-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the sample code below and modify your code accordingly.

Navigation Activity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigationActivity);

    Button btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Launcher.this,Activity2.class);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode ==  200)
    {

        String enteredText = "no action defined for this requestcode :"+resultCode;
        if(requestCode == 100)
        {
            enteredText = (String)data.getStringExtra("SearchText");

        }
        Toast.makeText(Launcher.this,enteredText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(Launcher.this,"some exception occurred",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

SEARCH ACTIVITY

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    Button btnGO = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
    btnGO .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            EditText edtSearchBar = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.tvTest);

               intent.putExtra("SearchText", edtSearchBar .getText().toString());

            setResult(200,intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried removing finish() but it still didn't work. Its navigating back to the NavigationActivity but the onActivityResult() is still not getting called in the NavigationActivity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that and it worked. I'm able to get the data that I entered in the SearchActivity to be displayed in the NavigationActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it need to be the other way around?

From my understanding you need to call `startActivityForResult(..)` from your `NavigationActivity` and not from the `SearchActivity`.

In `NavigationActivity`:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
```

And then in the `SearchActivity` call

```
setResult(..);
finish();
```

to get the result back to the calling activity and trigger your `onActivityResult(..)`method.

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985694/620338).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try calling the startActivityForResult() in the NavigationActivity and the setResult(),finish() and onActivityResult() methods in the SearchActivity. But could you please tell me where in the NavigationActivity should I call the startActivityForResult()?

Comment: It is not quite clear how your application works. In your question you wrote that NagivationActivity is the "previous activity". This indicates that SearchActivity is started by NavigationActivity. If not, please describe the workflow of your application.

Comment: Yes, the SearchActivity is started by the NavigationActivity only. I called the startActivityForResult() method in the NavigationActivity and the setResult(), finish() and onActivityResult() methods in the SearchActivity but its still not working. The onActivityResult() method is not getting called.

Comment: No, `onActivityResults()` needs to be in the calling method (`NavigationActivity`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I called the onActivityResult() method in the NavigationActivity and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult` is used to return data from called Activity to calling activity, i.e. if activity A is calling B, you can use `startActivityForResult` to return data from B to A