# onActivityResult not beeing called

Tags: android

First I think I should describe my problem:
I want to do a BluetoothRequest for turning it on, but I don't want to create a new Activity. I want to keep it in the MainActivity and put the code in subclasses. How is this possible? Down is my own idea of how to do it, but it don't works.

I have the MainActivity and a BluetoothActivity. The following code is from BluetoothActivity:

```
public class Bluetooth extends Fragment{
    private Context context;
    private TextView textView;
    private final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private String BtName;
    private String BtAddress;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    public Bluetooth(Context context){
        //constructor
        this.context=context;
        textView =  new TextView(this.context);
    }
    public boolean bluetoothUnterstuetz(){
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            //Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            textView.setText("Device doesn't support Bluetooth");
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void bluetoothActivate(){
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.getState()== BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON){
            textView.setText("Bluetooth already on.");
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        ((Activity) context).setContentView(textView);
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        textView.setText(resultCode);
        Log.i("bluetooth", "called");
        ((Activity) context).setContentView(textView);
    }
```

With extends Fragment nothing happens, also logcat is empty. With extends Activity, the app crashs after starting.
When I test the App on my Phone, I get the BluetoothRequest and can Choose my answer but afterwards the ContentView shows nothing, also Logcat stays empty

Somebody knows how to get the Result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984233/onactivityresult-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Well now it works. 
The `onActivityResult()` has to be in the MainActivity. If I put it into the subclass it won't be called

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten tag override.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> AndroidStudio tells me the function onActivityResult is never used.

Using the annotation `@Override` will make this warning to disappear. It is also a good way to check you overrided properly (with the right parameters in the right order) as you will get an error should the override be wrong. Which doesn't look to be the case here if you extended `Activity`.

> When I test the App on my Phone, I get the BluetoothRequest and can Choose my answer but afterwards the ContentView shows nothing.

Are you sure your `startActivityForResult()` was called and returned a result (ie. didn't call `finish()` for example)? I'll update my answer according to the details you will provide.

Comment: Yes `startActivityForResult()` is called, because by uncomment the row I don't get the Request.
It should deliver a result, but i'm not able to call the `onActivityResult()` function

Comment: @phenixclaw You don't have to call onActivityResult(). The system does it for you once the Activity you have called has finished.

Comment: Well if I don't open a second Activity and I'm just using the Mainactivity it won't work? I need to open a second Activity just for the Request?

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult` is a protected method of `Activity` and a public method of `Fragment`. If ide is warning you that the method is never used is because your class does not extend neither `Activity` nor `Fragment`

Comment: yes I don't had used Fragment and Activity. With activity the app crashed with starting the app, now with Fragment the warning no longer exists, but onActivityResult is not called.
As I understood the declaration, [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) the onActivityResult should be called automatically
"The REQUEST_ENABLE_BT constant passed to startActivityForResult() is a locally defined integer (which must be greater than 0), that the system passes back to you in your onActivityResult() implementation as the requestCode parameter."
@Shlublu

Comment: update  your question. It is almost impossible to understand what's going on without seeing the code